# Function to validate every X days between dates

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two Date objects. I would need a function to check if a number of days between two dates matches an 'every X number of days'. 
So if dates are May 10 and 13 or May 10 and May 19, function would return true if I query for every 3 days. But if I query every 2 days, it would return false.

Something like

```
function validateGap(date1, date2, numberOfDays) {//...return true or false}

date1 = new Date("May 10, 2020 00:00:00"),
date2 = new Date("May 13, 2020 00:00:00");
validateGap(date1, date2, 3) // = TRUE
validateGap(date1, date2, 2) // = FALSE


date1 = new Date("May 10, 2020 00:00:00"),
date2 = new Date("May 22, 2020 00:00:00");

validateGap(date1, date2, 5) // = FALSE
validateGap(date1, date2, 4) // = TRUE
```

and so on.

**UPDATE:** I came up with this. It surely isn't the most performance-wise solution but it works.

```
function validateGap(date1, date2, numberOfDays) {
while (date1 <= date2) {
  date1.setDate(date1.getDate()+numberOfDays);
  if (date1.valueOf() === date2.valueOf()) return true;
}
  return false;
}

date1 = new Date("May 10, 2020 00:00:00"),
date2 = new Date("May 13, 2020 00:00:00");

validateGap(date1, date2, 2); // FALSE
validateGap(date1, date2, 3); // TRUE
```

Comment: `validateGap(date1, date2, 4)` between may 10 and may 22 are not 4 days... why should it return true there?

Comment: There are many questions and answers about [how to get the difference between two dates in days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates). There is no attempt here to use those answers to write some code, it seems like a request for others to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

this tests if AT LEAST the number of days lays between date1 and date2... hope this is what you need...

i ignored `validateGap(date1, date2, 4) // = TRUE`, because i don't see the rule behind this, if you'd clarify, i could incorporate it...

```js
function validateGap(date1, date2, numberOfDays) {
  let diff = date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf();
  if (diff < 0) {
    diff *= -1;
  }
  const diffInDays = diff / (1000 * 60*60*24);
  return diffInDays % numberOfDays === 0;
}

date1 = new Date("May 10, 2020 00:00:00"),
date2 = new Date("May 13, 2020 00:00:00");
console.log('validation result:',validateGap(date1, date2, 3), ' | expected result:', true) // = TRUE
console.log('validation result:',validateGap(date1, date2, 2), ' | expected result:',false) // = FALSE

date1 = new Date("May 10, 2020 00:00:00"),
date2 = new Date("May 22, 2020 00:00:00");
console.log('validation result:',validateGap(date1, date2, 5), ' | expected result:', false); // = FALSE
console.log('validation result:',validateGap(date1, date2, 4), ' | expected result:', true); // = TRUE
```

---

UPDATE

op is asking for every 2nd, 3rd, and so on day... so I updated the line

```
return numberOfDays >= diffInDays;
```

to

```
return diffInDays % numberOfDays === 0;
```

Comment: I forgot the most important thing, added it to the question

Comment: Thank you! This works, but only if the difference is like less than a month. On greater differences it always returns false. Are the numeric values too high then or...? I'd appreciate If you could take a look at this. For example, when date1 = "Mar 02" and date2 = "May 12"

Comment: when date1 = "Mar 02" and date2 = "May 12" and numberOfDays = ?

Comment: for example numberOfDays = 3